# latex macro fails to parse expression although bracket groups match

Tags: macros, etoolbox, recursion

The `tensor` package allows the typesetting of tensors using commands like,

```
\[
     \tensor{X}{^b^o_a_t}
\]
```

to produce the following expression:

[image]

Together with the `physics` package it is possible to typeset
expressions involving tensors of tensors like for example,

```
\[
      \tensor{\qty(\tensor{\qty(\tensor{T}{^g^o_a_t})}{^b^o_x})}{^d^o_g}
\]
```

As you can see, as the number of imbedded tensors increases, keeping track of brackets becomes
more difficult. I am trying to write a macro that does this but when I compile the code I get the following error:

```
f:/tensorgroup/tensorgroup.tex:84: Argument of \stensor  has an extra }.
```

The whole code is shown below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV=15,parskip=full]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{physics} 
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

% group tensor list is supgroup0,subgroup0]supgrroup1,subgroup1]...
% supgroupN is letter0:letter1:... (same for subgroupN)

\NewDocumentCommand{\stensor}{m m}
{
    \setsepchar{,/:}
    \greadlist*\indices{#2}   % indices are superscripts,subscripts with letters separated by :
    \def\expression{}
    \def\sups{}
    \foreach \i in {1, ...,\listlen\indices[1]}
    {
        \xappto\sups{^\indices[1,\i]}
    }
    \def\subs{}
    \foreach \i in {1, ...,\listlen\indices[2]}
    {
        \xappto\subs{_\indices[2,\i]}
    }
    \xappto\expression{\noexpand\tensor{#1}{\sups \subs}}
    \expression
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\gtensor}{m m}
{
    \setsepchar{,/:}
    \greadlist*\indices{#2}   % indices are superscripts,subscripts with letters separated by :
    \def\fish{}
    \def\sups{}
    \foreach \i in {1, ...,\listlen\indices[1]}
    {
        \xappto\sups{^\indices[1,\i]}
    }
    \def\subs{}
    \foreach \i in {1, ...,\listlen\indices[2]}
    {
        \xappto\subs{_\indices[2,\i]}
    }
    \xappto\fish{\noexpand\tensor{\noexpand\qty(#1)}{\sups \subs}}
    \fish   
}

\NewDocumentCommand{\evalgtensor}{m m}
{
    \setsepchar{]/,/:}
    \readlist\allidx{#2}
    \def\bird{}
    \foreach \i in {2, ...,\listlen\allidx[]}
    {
        \xappto\bird{ \noexpand\gtensor{ }
    }
    \xappto\bird{\noexpand\stensor{#1}{\allidx[1]}}
    \foreach \i in {2, ...,\listlen\allidx[]}
    {
        \xappto\bird{  }{\allidx[\i]}}
    }
    {\bird}
}

\begin{document}

\[
\stensor{T}{g:o,a:t}
\]

\[
\gtensor{T}{g:o,a:t}
\]

\[
\evalgtensor{T}{g:o,a:t]b:o,x]d,o:g]f:l:o,a:t}    
%\gtensor{\gtensor{\gtensor{\stensor{T}{g:o,a:t}}{b:o,x}}{d,o:g}}{f:l:o,a:t}
\]

\end{document}
```

The equation,

```
\[
\gtensor{\gtensor{\gtensor{\stensor{T}{g:o,a:t}}{b:o,x}}{d,o:g}}{f:l:o,a:t}
\]
```

works and produces the desired result.

[image]

I have made sure that in the `\evalgtensor` command
I avoid newbie errors like unmatched curly brackets. If I replace commands like `\gtensor`
with `gtensor` , `\stensor` with `stensor` and convert `{` and `}` to `\{` and `\}` I get text for which brackets match. But for some reason, when the actual macros
are in the `\evalgtensor` macro it fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd not use `\left` and `\right` like `physics` does. And I'd not use `physics` at all, to be honest.

Here's an implementation with an easy syntax:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tensor}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\gtensor}{mm}
 {% #1 is the symbol, #2 the list of tensor indices
  \tedblack_gtensor:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__tedblack_tensor:nn { \tensor{#1}{#2} }

\seq_new:N \g__tedblack_gtensor_list_seq
\tl_new:N \l__tedblack_gtensor_out_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \tedblack_gtensor:nn
 {
  \tl_set:Nx \l__tedblack_gtensor_out_tl
   {
    \__tedblack_tensor:nn { #1 } { \tl_item:nn { #2 } { 1 } }
   }
  \int_step_inline:nnn { 2 } { \tl_count:n { #2 } }
   {
    \tl_set:Nx \l__tedblack_gtensor_out_tl
     {
      \__tedblack_tensor:nn
       { \group_begin: (\exp_not:V \l__tedblack_gtensor_out_tl) \group_end: }
       { \tl_item:nn { #2 } { ##1 } }
     }
   }
   \tl_use:N \l__tedblack_gtensor_out_tl
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
\gtensor{T}{
 {^g^o_a_t}
 {^b^o_x}
 {^d^o_g}
 {^f^l^o_a_t}
}
\]

\end{document}
```

The idea is to build step by step the whole expression from inside to outside, adding parentheses after the first step where the base symbol is used.

[image]

If you replace `\group_begin: (` with `\left(` and `) \group_end:` with `\right)`, you get

[image]

I find it unsightly.

Comment: This is thoroughly impressive. I will spend the rest of the summer studying this post so that I can improve my latex programming. By the way your style comments are very welcome.